# Dapper - return GUID generated by SQL Server

Tags: dapper

All of the Dapper posts on S/O related to returning a value after insert seem to relate only to the Identity value.  I have tried to apply the logic in those answers to my issue, but it's not working.

I want to return a GUID generated by SQL Server which is **not** an Identity field.  This is my code:

```
public bool Insert(Record record)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Production"));
    connection.Open();
    using (connection)
    {
        string query = "DECLARE @RSGUID uniqueidentifier SET @RSGUID = NEWID(); INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Result], [ResultSetKey]) VALUES (@Result, @RSGUID); SELECT @RSGUID";
        // it's this next line that I'm confused on:
        var resultSetKey = connection.Query<string>(query, @RSGUID).Single();
        return connection.Execute(query, record) > 0;
    }
}
```

I know the `var resultsSetKey` line is not correct, and this is what I need help with.  How can I get the GUID generated by SQL Server into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I can't test right now, but this should work:

```
public bool Insert(Record record)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Production"))
    {
        string query = "DECLARE @RSGUID uniqueidentifier; SET @RSGUID = NEWID(); INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Result], [ResultSetKey]) VALUES (@Result, @RSGUID); SELECT @RSGUID";
        var resultSetKey = connection.ExecuteScalar<string>(query).SingleOrDefault();
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(resultSetKey);
    }
}
```

You can get a kickstart with Dapper following the tutorial here:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/get-started-with-dapper-net-591592c335aa

but honestly it's really not clear what you are trying to do. What is the @Result variable that you are using in the T-SQL code?

Comment: Yeah there's an issue here for sure, and it may be b/c I don't fully understand what's happening in Dapper either, and sorry, I should have been more clear what I'm doing here.  `@Result` is being passed from Javascript as a value that's entered in a form on the webpage by the user.   So, using your code, I'm now getting the error: Must declare the scalar variable `@Result`.  But if I DON'T declare `@RSGUID` at the beginning of the SQL Statement and just start with INSERT INTO, the `@Result` is populated with the aforementioned value from Javascript. Now I'm more confused...

Comment: ....  I need to be able to have that `@Result` properly passed, and well as get the GUID returned to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help and nevermind, I went ahead and went a different route.  I think I was confusing the issue too much.

Answer (score 0):

A very old question, I know - but I've just had exactly the same issue here and found a working solution, so I'm sure somebody else will in benefit from this late answer in the future.

The following works as desired. The key for me was understanding the datatype to use in C# to contain the returned `stream_id` value, which is `System.Guid`, **not** `string`. Though of course you may wish to convert it to a string to display it to a user for example as plain text.

My stored procedure for entering a new file into the filetable is

```
USE [dbname]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[newFile]    Script Date: 28/11/2022 14:34:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[newFile] 
    @fileBinary varbinary(max) = 0,
    @fileName varchar(256) = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @newFileId table (stream_id uniqueidentifier);
    INSERT INTO dbo.files (file_stream, name) OUTPUT INSERTED.[stream_id] into @newFileId
    VALUES (@fileBinary, @fileName);
    SELECT * FROM @newFileId
END
```

And here is the method to add said new file programmatically (I'm fully aware this example includes no error handling etc)

```
public class fileAccess
{
    public System.Guid newFileId;

    public void uploadNewFile(byte[] newFileBinary, string newFileName)
    {
        var procedure = "[newFile]";
        var parameters = new
        {
            fileBinary = newFileBinary,
            fileName = newFileName,
        };

        using (DbConnection connection = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(helper.cnnVal("dbname")))
        {
            newFileId = connection.ExecuteScalar<System.Guid>(procedure, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
}
```

Called here (a test example, uploading a file by clicking a button, which pulls a file from my desktop)

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileAccess db = new fileAccess();
        byte[] fileBinary = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.docx");
        db.uploadNewFile(fileBinary, "test.docx");
        string message = "New file succesfully uploaded. File ID: " + Convert.ToString(db.newFileId);
        string caption = "Success.";
        MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
```